# Can accuracy_score and precision_score be equal?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to build a logistic regression model in python 3 using sklearn library.

Let's stick to below short versions going forward,

dv - dependent variable

idv - independent variable

Now I have idv1, idv2, idv3, idv4, idv5, idv6, idv7, idv8 & idv9.

Out of which idv6 to idv9 are categorical variables (idv6 & idv7 has 3 categories..where as idv8 & idv9 are boolean variables..yes or no kind of variables [0 or 1])

And dv is again a boolean variable (yes or no kind of variable).

Now, I have created a dummies for all idv6 to idv9 for the final model data...i.e idv6_c1, idv6_c2, idv_c3 and followed similar for the remaining..like idv8_c1, idv8_c2 for idv8 & idv9.

Now, after fitting the model and finding the metrics of the predicted values...

I am getting let's say *accuracy_score* of **76.7415479670124 %** and  *precision_score* of **76.7415479670124 %**

I have calculated using **sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score** and **sklearn.metrics.precision_score** libraries.

I am wondering..is this correct or am I missing something...??

Can this happen ??...accuracy & precision to be equal to almost 13 decimals ???....I am sure...I am doing something wrong...can anyone please help me ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precision = True Positive / (True Positive + False Positive)

Accuracy = (True Positive + True Negative) / (True Positive + False Positive + True Negative + False Negative)

Therefore, if there are no negative predictions, these two values will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Precision is defined as the fraction of retrieved results that are relevant, given by: (tp/tp+fp), while accuracy is the ratio of correct predictions to total number of input samples.

Although less likely, but it can happen that precision is equal to accuracy, when both number of true negatives and false negatives is zero. That is, your system does not classify any sample as negative.

Your problem however could be related to  micro-averaging as mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99694/what-does-it-imply-if-accuracy-and-recall-are-the-same).

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://simonhessner.de/why-are-precision-recall-and-f1-score-equal-when-using-micro-averaging-in-a-multi-class-problem/) to solve the same score result and more detailed principles.

You just need to change the parameters of scikit-learn.

`average = macro` or `average = weighted`

Codes and result are copy from the link above. (https://simonhessner.de/why-are-precision-recall-and-f1-score-equal-when-using-micro-averaging-in-a-multi-class-problem/)

References: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html

```
print("Precision (micro): %f" % precision_score(labels, predicitons, average='micro'))
print("Recall (micro):    %f" % recall_score(labels, predicitons, average='micro'))
print("F1 score (micro):  %f" % f1_score(labels, predicitons, average='micro'), end='\n\n')

print("Precision (macro): %f" % precision_score(labels, predicitons, average='macro'))
print("Recall (macro):    %f" % recall_score(labels, predicitons, average='macro'))
print("F1 score (macro):  %f" % f1_score(labels, predicitons, average='macro'), end='\n\n')

print("Precision (weighted): %f" % precision_score(labels, predicitons, average='weighted'))
print("Recall (weighted):    %f" % recall_score(labels, predicitons, average='weighted'))
print("F1 score (weighted):  %f" % f1_score(labels, predicitons, average='weighted'))
```

will get this result:

```
    Precision (micro): 0.444444
    Recall (micro): 0.444444
    F1 score (micro): 0.444444

    Precision (macro): 0.366667
    Recall (macro): 0.361111
    F1 score (macro): 0.355556

    Precision (weighted): 0.433333
    Recall (weighted): 0.444444
    F1 score (weighted): 0.429630
```